# writing java program with repeated main menu

Tags: java, command-line, menu

I've spent hours on this program trying to figure out how to repeat the main menu to show until the user write 3 (to quit the program).

The program asks the user to enter 2 integer numbers, then Main menu shows to choose from 3 options.

I chose the do while loop to force it show at least once, but i don't know what's my mistake?

---

```
   package javaapplication33;
     import static java.lang.System.exit;
      import java.util.Scanner;

   public class JavaApplication33 {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter two numbers: ");
    int n1 = input.nextInt();
    int n2 = input.nextInt();
    int multb = n1 * n2;

    int optionn = showMenu();

    do {

        switch (optionn) {

            case 1:
                int sum = n1 + n2;
                System.out.println(sum);

                break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println(n1 + "*" + n2 + " = " + multb);
                break;
            case 3:
                exit(0);
            default:
                System.out.println("Sorry, please enter valid Option");
                showMenu();
        }// End of switch statement

    } while (optionn == 3);
    System.out.println("Thank you. Good Bye.");

}


public static int showMenu() {

    int optionn = 0;
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Main Menu:");
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("1.Add the numbers");
    System.out.println("2.Multiply the numbers");
    System.out.println("3.Quit");
    System.out.println("--------------");
    System.out.println("Enter your choice:");
    optionn = keyboard.nextInt();

    return optionn;

}
```

Comment: Did any of the solutions work for you or are you still experiencing issues?

Answer (score 4):

You could consider just a while loop, instead of a do-while.

```
int optionn = 0;
while (optionn != 3)
{
   optionn = showMenu();
   switch (optionn) {
        case 1:
            int sum = n1 + n2;
            System.out.println(sum);

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(n1 + "*" + n2 + " = " + multb);
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter valid Option");
    }
}
```

Additionally, there's no reason to clear out your optionn variable in your showMenu method.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of mistakes.

First you should be getting the user input inside the `do`/`while` loop. Just move your `optionn=showMenu()` inside the do (That way you can show the options again and allow the user to choose again).

Second you want to keep on looping while `optionn!=3` instead of `optionn==3` (You want to continue looping if the user doesn't want to exit).

I would also not use `exit(0)` and also move your exit print statement to inside the loop (So you print it before you exit your function). Something like this:

```
int n1 = input.nextInt();
int n2 = input.nextInt();
int multb = n1 * n2;
int optionn;
do {
    optionn = showMenu();  //Allow user to select from menu every iteration
    switch (optionn) {
    case 1:
        int sum = n1 + n2;
        System.out.println(sum);
        break;
    case 2:
        System.out.println(n1 + "*" + n2 + " = " + multb);
        break;
    case 3:
        System.out.println("Thank you. Good Bye."); //Moved from the bottom
        return;  //I would use return instead of the exit(0) here.
        //exit(0);
    default:
        System.out.println("Sorry, please enter valid Option");
        showMenu();
    }// End of switch statement
} while (optionn != 3); //Make sure this is != not ==
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The two lines of code that needed fixing - have comments, see below:

```
do {

    switch (optionn) {

        case 1:
            int sum = n1 + n2;
            System.out.println(sum);

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(n1 + "*" + n2 + " = " + multb);
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter valid Option");
    }// End of switch statement
    optionn = showMenu();  // <--- changed
} while (optionn != 3);    // <--- changed
```

Comment: I don't think the last print statement ever gets called? Correct?

Comment: @gonzo true. It's redundant.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
do {

    switch (optionn) {

        case 1:
            int sum = n1 + n2;
            System.out.println(sum);

            break;
        case 2:
            System.out.println(n1 + "*" + n2 + " = " + multb);
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
        default:
            System.out.println("Sorry, please enter valid Option");
            showMenu();
    }// End of switch statement
    int optionn = showMenu();//SHOWS THE MENU AGAIN
} while (optionn == 3);
System.out.println("Thank you. Good Bye.");
```

Your showmenu() method isnt in your while that why i dosent repeat